# Specific origin of savvy

Tags: etymology

The dictionaries don't agree on whether savvy comes from French or Spanish, via creole/pidgin. Is it known which language is the origin and where the word specifically first entered English?

Comment: [link](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=savvy)

Comment: Portuguese *sabe* has also been mentioned as a possible etymon.

Answer (score 1):

The word is currently recorded as a noun, adjective, and verb in my copy of the OED. It seems the noun is the oldest form.

Full credit to [EtymOnline](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=savvy) for this one:

> **savvy (n.)** 1785, "practical sense, intelligence;" also a verb, "to know, to understand;" West Indies
>   pidgin borrowing of French savez(-vous)? "do you know?" or Spanish
>   sabe (usted) "you know," both from Vulgar Latin *sapere, from Latin
>   sapere "be wise, be knowing" (see sapient). The adjective is first
>   recorded 1905, from the noun. Related: Savvily; savviness.

Answer (score 0):

According to [The Dictionary of American Slang, Fourth Edition by Barbara Ann Kipfer, PhD. and Robert L. Chapman, Ph.D.](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/savvy) it is from Spanish, modern use is influenced by French:

> - [fr West Indian pidgin fr Spanish sabe usted, ''do you know?''; modern use influenced by French savez, ''you know'']